# How to configure compiler in debian os QT kit

Tags: qt, debian

I installed QT creator in debian linux. If I try to create a new project, in Kit option I got the error like "No valid Kit found". If I go to Tools ->Options -> Build&Run -> kit, there is no options to select. But I installed same in ubuntu, it is working fine without same problem. What im missing?

Also suggest me if I need to reinstall the QT creator or something else...

Comment: Do you have installed Qt or only Qt creator?

Comment: @Orest:QT creator in debian linx OS

Comment: Have you tried to set it manually? 
Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> Qt Versions -> Add...
Here select your qmake executable.

Comment: You should check that you have actual Qt Kit installed. You can find it by qmake on your file system. The path may be, for example, `<base>/5.3/gcc/bin/qmake`. You may need package https://packages.debian.org/sid/qt5-default and its dependency.

Comment: @agold: i tried  Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> Qt Versions -> Add , there is no qmake executable is showing.how to find out qmake executable installed or not

Comment: Like Orest Hera mentioned, you should make sure you have the Qt Kit actually installed. To find qmake you could do a `whereis qmake` or `locate qmake`.

Comment: @agold: if i type whereis qmake it is showing qmake: /usr/bin/qmake and for locate qmake it is showing 9 paths like qmake/project.pro , qmake/wizard.xml Actually im very new to this. please guide me what is the next step

Comment: What does `qmake --version` tell you?
If I run it, it shows `QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.0 in /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib` therefore qmake is in `/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin`.

Comment: @agold:if i type qmake --version it is showing like , qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory :(

Comment: Have you installed Qt? T `apt-get install qt5-default`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90978/discussion-between-sivanesan-and-agold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its time to explain the tricks to install QT creator in debian linux operating system.
>
> ***STEP 1:*** dont install just QT creator in your PC.
> Install whole package of QT [link to download QT SDK below][1]

[1]: http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 , so that you will get all the libraries and dependencies.

> After downloading the file is in the ".run" format . Install the downloaded file in your terminal (by giving commands).
>
> ***STEP 2:*** install
> **sudo apt-get install g++**
>
> **sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev**
>
> in your terminal.
>
> ***STEP 3:*** install
>
> **sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module**
>
> ***sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386***
>
> now restart your system once and create new project.It should work
>
> I like to thank  agold for his guidance , Actually he spent more than 3 hours to resolve this issue. :)